# Selecting the next tag using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have a `select` and 2 `td` tags as below.

```
<select name="accesslevel"><option value="A1">A1</option>
<option value="A2">A2</option></select>

<td id="Level3">

<td id="Level4">
```

I need to hide the `td` with Level3 id if A1 is selected in the select and show the td with Level4 id, and vice-versa.

The combination is repeated many times in the html so, i have to find the next `td`'s only after the `select` tag using jQuery.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your Select is also inside a TD of the same TR

```
$("#accesslevel").change(function(){ //give an id to your select box
  if(condition){
    $(this).parent().nextAll("#Level3").hide();
    $(this).parent().nextAll("#Level4").show();
  }
});
```

This just gives you an idea. You can obviously optimize the code by storing the parent in a variable and then searching for other nodes.

The idea is to find the parent TD and then use nextAll to find the other TDs. You could also find the parent row TR and then use TR.children("#Level3")

Comment: Why not just use `#Level3` instead of the long traversal chain? `id`s are unique, there's no need to traverse through the DOM for the element

Comment: @Yi Jiang, Since this is inside a TABLE tag, each row could have the elements with the same id, especially in case of HTML being generated by the server with PHP/ASP

Comment: Is it sad that unlike almost every other language on SO, we are assuming that the OP's code is *invalid* instead of valid? But yes, I agree, better to be safe than sorry in cases like this...

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("select[name='accesslevel']").change(function(){    
    if($(this).val()=="A1")    
    {    
        $(this).parent().next().find("td[id='Level3']").show();    
        $(this).parent().next().find("td[id='Level4']").hide();     
    }     
    if($(this).val()=="A2")     
    {
        $(this).parent().next().find("td[id='Level3']").hide();    
        $(this).parent().next().find("td[id='Level4']").show();    
    }
    });
});
```

See a working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dzPkk/3/)

Comment: This will work only if there is one row. Once you add multiple rows with elements having the same ids, it will hide ALL elements in all rows

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all your markup, I wonder if your `<select>` should be wrapped in a `<td>`?

```
<td><select>...</select></td>
<td class="level3">
<td class="level4">
```

In which case, you could do something like

```
$('select#someId').change(function() {
  var $nextTds = $(this).parents('td:first').nextAll('td:lt(2)');
  //manipulate $nextTds
]
```

If your `<td>` elements have IDs, this is not 'repeated' throughout the code as an ID is unique to every element - **the** `:lt(2)` **filter will only retrieve** `td` **elements of index** `0` **and** `1`.